# finding formula for M^n

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find formulas for the entries of $M^n$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

$M = [10 10]
    [-5 -5]$

My try:
I found eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and put $A$ as set of two eigenvectors and $D$ as eigenvalues. Then $ADA^{-1}$

I'm not getting right answer

Comment: What exactly is the matrix $M$ here? Are those the column or the row vectors of $M$ that you have given there?

Comment: 10,10 is the first row

Comment: If you calculate things right, you should get $0$ and $5$ as eigenvalues, but it's easier just to calculate $M^{2}$ in this case, and then things should be clear.